# Accessing MultiDim Array gives Seg Fault C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am doing a practise [problem](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA05/problems/KPRIME) in which I have to find Number of K-primes(Numbers having K distinct prime factors) between two given integers. I have coded the solution however I am getting a segmentation fault, I have pinpointed the location where I am getting Seg Fault

```
table[prime_factor_nos[i]][i]++;
```

I have created a global 2D array of size 6 by N(1e5 + 2). However when I reduce N to 1e4 it works as expected. For now I only know that improper indexing is not giving this issue rather memory.
I have also tried printing the values while looping, the seg fault occurs at this value

```
cout<<"i :"<<i<<" pf[i] "<<prime_factor_nos[i]<<" "<<table[prime_factor_nos[i]][i]<<nl
```

Seg fault occurs at i = 30015

Last output:

```
i :30014 pf[i] 3 0
i :
```

Is this a memory issue? Is the static storage not enough for this?

[Code](https://onlinegdb.com/SyYKEu8ow)

Comment: Try on the online ide.

Comment: @starboy_jb tried, same issue. Only difference terminated earlier. I have given the online ide link

Comment: For 30030, it has prime_factor_nos[30030] = 6, That's why it is causing a runtime error.

Comment: @starboy_jb Thanks! I overlooked that. Could you make an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 30030 and some more values, it has prime_factor_nos[30030] = 6, That's why it is causing a runtime error.